# Collapsing rows into one column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

If I have a dataframe like this with different product page for each user id and I want to group all product page of a user together separated by hyphen

[image]

and I want the end result like below

[image]

Is it easier to do this in pandas or sql? My dataset is currently 7.5MM rows and it would grow to ten of millions when used for more data.

In pandas can we use series.str.concatenate method to collapse and join by hyphen?

In sql suggestions?

Comment: How do we get from your example to your output? It's unclear where `-end` comes from, or where the `user_id` needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Even in R it is possible . Check dplyr group_by

Comment: Use Python and not R. -end is another text I add to the concatenated product page names. Basically V1 above is the concatenated product page for each user id.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, you can use a `groupby` with an anonymous function:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([(5, 'product'), (5, 'product'), (5, 'home'), (4, 'product'), (4, 'home')], columns=['user_id', 'page_category'])
>>> df
    user_id page_category
 0        5       product
 1        5       product
 2        5          home
 3        4       product
 4        4          home
>>> df.groupby('user_id')['page_category'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x))
 user_id
 4            product-home
 5    product-product-home
 Name: page_category, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is giving a series. I want like a sql table structure. Columns should be user_id, page_category (which is concat one). I tried as_index=False but not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If by "easier", you mean "faster", keep in mind that SQL is a database interface, not the database itself. How quickly this operation can be performed in the database depends on its architecture.

Comment: I hv mysql instance